# Function of noncommutative operators: how should the powers in its Taylor expansion be arranged, and how to take partial derivatives?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantization, non-commutative-theory

Let $F:\mathbb R ^n\to\mathbb R$ be a function that has a Taylor expansion, then it can be written (expanded at $a$) as
$$
F(x)=\sum_{\alpha} \frac{(x_1 - a_1)^{\alpha_1}\dots(x_n - a_n)^{\alpha_n}}{\alpha_1 !\dots \alpha_n !}\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}F(a)}{\partial_1^{\alpha_1}\dots \partial_n^{\alpha_n}}
$$
where multi-index is used, i.e. $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb N_0^n$ and $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_n$.

Now we take $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and the quantum mechanical operators $q$ and $p$ which do not commute, $[q,p] = i\hbar$, then (expanding at $a = 0$) there will be an ambiguity in the order (arrangement) of the powers of $q$ and $p$, since in general, for $m,n,j,k \in \mathbb N$,
$$
q^m p^n q^j p^k \neq q^{m+j} p^{n+k} \qquad \iff \qquad [q^m p^n q^j p^k,q^{m+j} p^{n+k}] \neq 0
$$
So which one should be in the expansion ? or should they be symmetrised ?

Another question is how do we take partial derivatives of such function of operators. For example of the product $q^m p^n q^j p^k $,
\begin{align}
\partial_p(q^m p^n q^j p^k) &= n (q^m p^{n-1} q^j p^k) \quad  ?\\
&=j (q^m p^n q^{j-1} p^k) \quad  ?\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n (q^m p^{n-1} q^j p^k) + j (q^m p^n q^{j-1} p^k)) \quad ?\\
& = ???
\end{align}

Comment: There is an infinity of ordering prescriptions, all equivalent and interconvertible to each other. Some popular ones are [Weyl ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner–Weyl_transform), normal ordering, anti-normal ordering, Born-Jordan ordering, etc... If you are taking derivatives w.r.t. noncommutative variables, you are being inefficient. There are consistent definitions of such, but there are better ways. You probably need to read up on the [phase-space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation).

Comment: "all are equivalent" means it doesn't matter which arrangement I choose, it gives the same operator $F(q,p)$ ? and what do you mean with "inefficient" ?

Comment: No, I mean you can systematically transform/translate from each one to any other one. Each prescription normally gives you different answers (amplitudes). But quantization prescription choice is subjective: ***nobody*** can dictate for you which one to choose. You decide which models your physics problem best. "Inefficient" means you are doing something "wrong": you are counting the centipede's legs and dividing by 100. The problem you might wish to solve this way most probably has a better solution within phase-space QM.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/operator-ordering-ambiguities), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10804/what-does-the-ordering-of-creation-annihilation-operators-mean), or [else](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57299/weyl-ordering-rule).

Comment: You might appreciate [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389944/on-groenewolds-theorem-and-classical-and-quantum-hamiltonians).