# Operator ordering (for the Groenewold-van Hove theorem)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Suppose we have the (un)usual Schrödinger representation $\pi'(\cdot)$ of the Heisenberg algebra, along with the extension in $\mathbb{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ for the quadratic polynomials. It is assumed that

$$
\pi'(q^3) = -iQ^3;\quad \pi'(p^3) = -iP^3,
$$

where $[Q,P] = i\mathbb{I}$ (the usual commutator in quantum mechanics). I want to prove that

$$
\pi'(q^2 p) = -\frac{i}{2}(Q^2P + PQ^2)\quad (1)
$$

using the Poisson bracket $\lbrace q^3,p^2\rbrace = 6q^2p$.

Is (1) correct? The most that I can do is, using that $\pi'$ is a linear map

$$
\begin{split}
\pi'(\frac{1}{6}\lbrace q^3,p^2 \rbrace) &= \frac{1}{6}[\pi'(q^3),\pi'(p^2)] \\
&= -\frac{1}{6}[Q^3,P^2]\\
&= -\frac{i}{6}(3QP^2 + 3P^2Q + 2QPQ),
\end{split}
$$

but I cannot get rid of the term $2QPQ$. Or is it that my commutator computation is wrong?

Comment: Related: [Operator Ordering Ambiguities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46988/2451), [What is the connection between Poisson brackets and commutators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of your commutator evaluation is definitely wrong.

It appears you are striving to calculate the [Groenewold anomaly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390192/66086) but I have failed to understand your bizarre "linear"  map of "the usual Schrödinger representation ′(⋅)" you posit to antihermitean operators, so I'll avoid it completely.

I'll just evaluate a few commutators correctly for you:
$$
[Q^3,P^2]= 3i ~(PQ^2 + Q^2 P),\\
[Q^2,P^3]= 3i ~(QP^2 + P^2 Q), ~~\leadsto \\
[[Q^3,P^2], [Q^2,P^3]]=   12[Q^3,P^3] +\mathbf{36}~.
$$
The last (boldfaced), constant, term is the celebrated ***Groenewold anomaly*** (has an $\hbar^2$ factor when you reinstate ℏ in your Heisenberg commutation relation).

Virtually  straightforward to compute in deformation quantization.

It corrects the classical limit expression
$$
\{\{q^3,p^2\}, \{q^2,p^3\}\}=   12\{q^3,p^3\} ,
$$
which has lost quantum information, as usual.

---

*Edit post comments*

Having found a copy of Woit's book, I at last appreciated the sadistic notation. His conceit (so 1930s) is to define a trial quantization map $i\pi'(q,p)$, Hermitian,  for the unambiguous low polynomial orders, and then attempt to ladder his way up to higher orders defining them through the chimeric desideratum
$$
\pi'(\{ f,g\})= [\pi'(f),\pi'(g)], 
$$
producing
$$
i\pi'(qp)=i\pi'(\{q^2,p^2\}/4)= -\frac{i}{4}[Q^2,P^2]=\tfrac{1}{2}(PQ+QP), 
$$(in Weyl ordering), and further producing your (1), which, however, is *not* in Weyl ordering! (You simply mishandled the commutator).

He then concludes his chapter by pointing out the hapless chimeric desideratum above is inconsistent, as the quartic term $\pi'(q^2p^2)$ is ill-defined, as evaluated in two alternate PB pathways. Mathematicians have these circuitous dandy arguments, but the point is *no* consistent  map can be found. Above, I condensed Groenewold's direct argument in one line, just as in our [booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf).

Comment: Well, the anti-Hermitian part it's Peter Woit's definition that appears in his book "Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations" :).

Comment: I think his motivation is between Mathematics and Physics and the differences in the literature. From the group property of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and a member $A=e^{t X}$ of it, the property $A A^\dagger = \mathbb{I}$ forces to have $X^\dagger = -X$. Then he says "Note that physicists often choose to define the Lie algebra in these cases as self-adjoint matrices ... We will not use this definition... we want to think of the Lie algebra as a real vector space..."

Comment: But this is only notation... I don't understand the "hapless quantization map" question but I was checking actually yesterday the answer that you linked and Sec. 14 of the book "Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space".

Comment: I think it's clear. I didn't know the factor of 36, since this is the first time I see it. It's exercise B8 tries to do something similar, but the expressions are different. 

Perhaps a closing question: is it not that we really care only for transition of the physical system $\langle x'|\rho|x\rangle$ (or only energy differences) and not really the operator ordering? Under this circumstances it would appear that canonical quantization is consistent up to a constant, similar to when we have a Lagrangian.

Comment: No, no quantization scheme is consistent. The whole dream of quantization is misplaced: it is like trying to determine a series for a function relying on its first term and a God-given recipe. There are several quantum systems, all logically consistent and legitimate, as per nature!, with a common classical limit.  It is nice to have canonical guidelines, but that's all they are. At the end of the day, you *guess* a richer theory, starting from a limited corner/limit of it...

Comment: As for his problem 1, Exercise B.8, multiply his last two lines by 9  to compare to our "concise" book. The above expression here has to be rearranged and divided by 12 to compare. All three expressions for the anomaly are identical.