# Why do we derive more fundamental quantum theories from less fundamental classical theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In almost every derivation of a quantum theory (quantum mechanics or quantum field theory), we start with a classical theory using classical equations and quantize it (by imposing certain constraints on commutation relations, etc).

My question is, isn't the entire process of starting with a classical theory (which is less fundamental) and deriving a quantum theory (which is presumably more fundamental) backwards? Why should we expect the correct fundamental quantum theory that describes our universe to be derivable from a less fundamental (averaged over, approximation) classical theory?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There are quantum theories for which no classical limit exists or multiple classical limits exist, etc.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3500/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245300/2451 and links therein.

Comment: OK but my real question is, if this is the case, why would we expect a more fundamental theory to be derivable from a less fundamental theory?

Comment: We don't derive it, we guess it. We hope to be able to guess correctly by using the guidance of experimental evidence. That's how all science works.

Comment: Existing attempts to derive quantum physics from axioms supposed to be more obvious or simple all seem to ring a bit hollow. The use of classical physics to provide pointers is much more fruitful in practice. We don't *derive* quantum from classical, but rather we get *insightful hints and suggestions.*

Comment: Saying that this is how we've made progress so far "rings hollow" to me. You could say the same to a bunch of monkeys who were trying to reach the moon and said they'd made the most progress by climbing higher and higher trees. It doesn't mean that approach will ever actually accomplish the task.