# Classic analog of quantum mechanics when dealing with Hamiltonian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

I am reading `The Principles of Quantum Mechanics by Dirac`, in chapter 28 `Heisenberg's form for the equations of motion`, there is a statement about the classic analog about the Hamiltion form between classic mechanics of and quantum mechanics. My questions are:

1. If classic analog means that the Hamiltonian operator is the function of $q$ and $p$ (position and mom), then what is the premise of this assumption?
2. Is there any example of a Hamiltonian that couldn't be expressed as the function of $q$ and $p$?
3. There is a footnote saying that under Curvilinear coordinates, this assumption is NOT right, so I guess that under Curvilinear coordinates, the classic Hamiltonian form and quantum Hamiltonian form are NOT the same, is there an example of this situation? And why would this happen?

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by: "what is the premise of this assumption"; can you be more explicit on what you are asking?

Comment: @Noumeno I wanna know if there is an example that Hamiltonian is not the function of only p and q, except when there are external fields.

Comment: Arguably [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297279/dequantizing-diracs-quantization-rule/297293#297293).

Answer (score 2):

Quantization/dequantization is a huge topic, so we will only try to address OP's specific questions:

1. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245300/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The simplest example is perhaps spin/internal angular momentum operators $\hat{S}_x,\hat{S}_y,\hat{S}_z$.
3. Dirac is referring to operator ordering ambiguities, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111216/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296519/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: So if I dequantize a quantum theory, an operator degenerate into a function, is there any geometry concepts analog of this process?

Comment: @Jack there is an entire cottage industry of the limits of metaplectic geometry. Perhaps you'd like to brush up on deformation quantization and geometric quantization. It's subtle.

Comment: There are literally dozens of books in the market. Start by trawling in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization), and [especially here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation), and explore the books in the literature. Might take a look at [this one](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf).