# Squaring the momentum operator in QM becomes a second derivative. How?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, operators, momentum, differentiation

$\frac{p^2}{2m}$ is the Kinetic energy in classical mechanics. However, the same $p^2$ becomes the second derivative $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}$ in the Kinetic Energy operator in QM. I mean it is strange that a squaring process of a differential in an operator becomes the double differential. How was it deduced in the first place?

Comment: What would you expect the square of an operator to do if not apply the operator twice?

Answer (score 2):

1. Squaring an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) $\hat{A}$ means [composing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) it with itself $$\hat{A}^{\circ 2}~:=~\hat{A}\circ\hat{A}.$$
   Usually, the composition symbol "$\circ$" is not written explicitly.
2. As for the dictionary between functions in classical mechanics (CM) and operators in quantum mechanics (QM), see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139190/2451). In particular, a function multiplied with itself in CM becomes an operator composed with itself in QM (up to possible quantum corrections).