# Why operator of kinetic energy has a double derivative instead of square of single derivative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, hamiltonian, differentiation

I know that operator for $p = {h\over i} {d\over dx}$.
so $p = {h\over i} {d\psi\over dx}$ where $\psi$ is the wave function.

So, $T$ (kinetic energy) $ = {p^2 \over 2m} = {-h^2\over 2m} {d\psi \over dx}^2$,
so the operator for $T$ should be $-{h^2\over 2m} \left({d\over dx}\right)^2$ and not $d^2\over dx^2$.

Please explain where I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Squaring the momentum operator in QM becomes a second derivative. How?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403443/2451)

Comment: You can write Psi using: \psi inside \$ \$. Eg: $\psi$

Comment: Squaring an operator is, by definition, applying it twice.

Comment: "*... should be $\left({d\over dx}\right)^2$ and not $d^2\over dx^2$*". They are the exact same thing: $\left({d\over dx}\right)^2\equiv \frac{d^2}{ dx^2}$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550600/289977 and links therein.

Comment: The usual heuristic argument for *why* Schödinger's equation (which I recapitulate in an earlier post https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/290697/520), gives a hint that might make it more intuitive: you have to *apply* the operator to get the necessary factor of $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum operator is defined as:

$$\hat{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$$

This means that if you want to get the momentum from the wavefunction $\psi$, you must apply the momentum operator to the wavefunction. Let's define the wavefunction as:

$$\psi=A\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(px-Et\right)\right]$$

It is easy to see that:

$$\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\psi=p\psi$$

If you want to get $p^2$ you have to apply the momentum operator to the wavefunction twice.

$$\hat{p}^2\psi=\hat{p}\hat{p}\psi=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\psi\right)=p\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\psi\right)=p^2\psi$$

So the $\hat{p}^2$ operator is:

$$\hat{p}^2=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\right)=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\right)^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=-\hbar^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

We have $$p^2\psi=\hat{p}^2\psi=\hat{p}\hat{p}\psi=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=-\hbar^2\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}.$$

Comment: By using `\left(` and `\right)` you can get re-sizing parenthesis. It also work with other brackets: say `\left[ x^{x^x}\right\}` to get $\left[ x^{x^x}\right\}$ (note that you have to escape the `{`).

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. However the difference is zero for the expectation value as the space integral over both expressions differs only by a partial integration.

Comment: My answer is correct and equivalent to the other two answers. I just don't a) think I have to sp