# Poisson brackets of three dimensional angular momentum and its Lie algebra

Tags: angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, rotation, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets

I've recently noticed that the Poisson brackets of the three dimensional angular momentum $$\{L_i,L_j\}$$ in classical mechanics follow the same commutator relations as the standard basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. This means that these to Lie algebras are isomorphic.

Also $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is the Lie algebra of the Lie group ${\rm SO}(3)$, which is the group of three dimensional rotations.

This seems very geometric to me. My question is therefore: Is there a geometric way to interpret Poisson brackets (of angular momenta or in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice observation! This is the geometric picture: in this example you have a Hamiltonian action of the Lie group $SO(3)$ on the phase space $T^\star \mathbb R^3$ associated to a 3D particle. The angular momenta $L_i$ collectively define the moment map for this map. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_map) on moment maps and in particular the second paragraph under "Examples of momentum maps" which treats precisely this example.

The general case of course is that of a Hamiltonian action of a Lie group on the phase space under consideration.

Answer (score 6):

1. The $j$th component of the angular momentum $L_j$ is the [Noether charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) for 3D rotation around the $j$th axis. It satisfies the $so(3)$ [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)
   $$\begin{align}\{L_j,L_k\}~=~& \epsilon_{jk\ell}L_{\ell},\cr j,k,\ell~\in~&\{1,2,3\}.\end{align}\tag{1}$$
   where the curly bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ denotes the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket).
2. The corresponding [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_{L_j}\equiv\{L_j,\cdot\}$ is the generator of 3D rotations around the $j$th axis, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE post. It satisfies the $so(3)$ Lie algebra $$\begin{align}[X_{L_j},X_{L_k}]~\stackrel{\text{Jac. id.}}{=}&~X_{\{L_j,L_k\}}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~~& X_{\epsilon_{jk\ell}L_{\ell}}~\cr
   \stackrel{\text{linearity}}{=}&~
   \epsilon_{jk\ell} X_{L_{\ell}}.\end{align}\tag{2}$$
3. Under quantization $L_j\to \hat{L}_j$ from functions to operators, the Poisson bracket (1) is replaced with commutators (divided by $i\hbar$):
   $$[\hat{L}_j,\hat{L}_k]~=~ i\hbar\epsilon_{jk\ell}\hat{L}_{\ell},\tag{3}$$
   cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) Phys.SE post.