# Relation between $SO(4)$ symmetry and conservation of LRL (Lagrangian-Runge-Lentz) vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, conservation-laws, group-theory, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18610/289541), conservation of LRL vector (classical and quantum)
$$
\vec A=\frac1{2m}(\vec p\times \vec L-\vec L\times \vec p)-\frac{q^2}{r}\hat r,
$$
was related to $SO(4)$ symmetry, but no further explanation was given.
Is it true? How can one prove it?

Comment: In [this doc, section D](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/wiki/uploads/projects/geomech/Alemicds205final.pdf), $SO(4)$ structure is mentioned. It's not lorentz symmetry.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.14416.pdf) is more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to see the ${\rm SO}(4)$ symmetry of the classical Kepler problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/603575/2451) Related: [How can one see that the Hydrogen atom has $SO(4)$ symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89654/2451)