# Is it in general? $[\Lambda,\Omega]=i\hbar\{\lambda,\omega\}_{x,p}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, commutator, poisson-brackets

In R. Shankar's book, He has written
$$[X_i,P_j]=i\hbar\{x_i,p_j\}=i\hbar$$
Is there any specific reason to use the Poisson bracket? Is there any general relation which looks like?
$$[\Lambda,\Omega]=i\hbar \{\lambda,\omega\}_{x,p}$$

Comment: Is this in reference to canonical quantisation? The classical algebra with the Poisson bracket becomes the quantum algebra with the commutator.

Comment: $\lambda(x,p)\rightarrow \hat{\Lambda}(\hat{X},\hat{P})$. Is that makes it clear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the connection between Poisson brackets and commutators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/)

Comment: It only works exactly for operators that are at most quadratic in $x$ and $p$. Beyond that there are $O(\hbar^2)$ corrections. This is the *Groenewold-van Hove no-go theorem*.